# Angular: How to correctly access data in Component

Tags: angular, rxjs, reactive-programming

I was wondering what was the correct way to access data in a component. I've read a couple times already that you should let angular templates handle subscriptions But how would you access current values for certain methods inside the `component.ts` file?

Suppose i have the following component:

```
@Component({...})
class TestComponent {

  testData: Observable<TestData>

  ngOnInit(){
    this.testData = this.service.getData().pipe(share())
  }
}
```

It has a `sendDataABCProperty` which sends the property `ABC` of our testData to some arbitrary service.

```
  sendDataABCProperty() {
    this.testData.pipe(first()).subscribe(data => this.service.sendData(data.abc))
  }
```

Now, when using the above approach i still have to subscribe to my data, exactly what i was trying to prevent.

Another way would be to copy the data and not use a stream, but since i'm trying to make it more reactive, that's a way i'ld like to avoid.

A further example would be some kind of "display and edit" component. 
Suppose I get the my display data from some service who I access afterwards aswell to update the data. But i need the id (of the data) for it. What would be the best way to access the id? Copying it at the beginning (using `tap()` / `subscribe()`)? Using a `BehaviorSubject`? Or something completely different?

Comment: Can you show us the service method?

Comment: If you don't want to subscribe, then you can use [tap()](https://rxjs.dev/api/operators/tap) operator instead of `subscribe()`.

Comment: The service should not matter. 
And neither does the tap trick, because i would still have to subscribe somewhere. I'm trying to rephrase it.

Answer (score 1):

There are several questions in your post, I'll address the part about getting an id.

I have a List component that displays a list of products. The user clicks on a product to display/edit it. I handle that with a `Subject/BehaviorSubject`

**In the service**

```
  private productSelectedSubject = new BehaviorSubject<number>(0);
  productSelectedAction$ = this.productSelectedSubject.asObservable();
```

**In the component (when the user clicks a product)**

```
  onSelected(productId: number): void {
    this.productService.selectedProductChanged(productId);
  }
```

**In the service**

I then have a stream property in the service whose pipeline is automatically re-executed each time a different selected product is emitted:

```
  selectedProduct$ = combineLatest([
    this.products$,                    // Stream of all products
    this.productSelectedAction$
  ]).pipe(
    map(([products, selectedProductId]) =>
      products.find(product => product.id === selectedProductId)
    ),
    tap(product => console.log('selectedProduct', product)),
    // do whatever else needs to be done when a new product is selected
  );
```

Does that answer that part of your question?

I have sample code here: https://github.com/DeborahK/Angular-RxJS

This video may also be useful: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Z76QlSpYcck

Comment: Yes, it does. So the approach with using a BehaviorSubject seems to be the way to go.

Comment: If you want to follow a reactive approach, then the code should "pass" data around by emitting that data into a stream. Any code that is "watching" for changes to that stream will be notified and will get the "passed" data.

Answer (score 0):

- You **cannot** access the data of service until you subscribe it. However, you can modify the data using pipe. But note that the modification only happens when you subscribe to the observable.
- I don't know this is what you want or not. You can also use **resolver** to get the data before the component load & retrieve the data using snapshot.That way you don't have to subscribe to a observable in your component.

Please read this article for more detail, https://alligator.io/angular/route-resolvers/